# C# command line in code

Tags: c#, command-line, console

I'm trying to run hidden console with this command "winsat formal" in my C# code, but it is giving an error in "Process.Start()".  Here is my code:

```
string command = "winsat formal";

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = command;
process.Start();
```

Comment: Which error? Maybe 'unrecognized command'?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass the parameters as follows.

```
Process process = new Process();

process.StartInfo.FileName = "winsat" ;

//in here you add as many parameters as needed
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "formal" ; 

process.Start();
```

**UPDATE 1**

If you go to "cmd" command line and type "winsat formal" does it work ? If not you need to do one of these

- Add the path to the "winsat" executable to the **PATH** environment variable
- Or specify the folder where the executable is located like this

> process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory =
>   "c:\your\path\toWinSat\executable\" ;

If it still does not work please let me know

**UPDATE 2**

//Have you tried proving a full path to the executable ?

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\windows\system32\winsat.exe"
```

Also there are **[other posible ways of calling the Start method that can be usefull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Process.Start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

Comment: I already did this, don't work...But if i use another command like "calc" it work

Comment: Could be a permissions issue... do you have admin rights on the computer?  Can you post the Inner Exception?

Comment: Evan Lewis: dont know how to use this.
But the Visual Studio open the prompt from the Debug path of the project, and when i give the command "winsat formal" says that is not recognize as internal command

Comment: Is not recognize an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: @MauricioGracia, the winsat is in \Windows\System32...But still the same error. The command just dont work in the program. Im searching on google and i guess this is a .Net problem

Comment: @MauricioGracia, i did a copy of the "Winsat" in Debug path and it worked. But i didnt understood why

Comment: @SaturninoMateus have you tried proving full path as the FileName (see UPDATE 2 of the answer)

Comment: @MauricioGracia if i do process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\windows\system32\winsat" 
it will only open the path. And "winsat" is a .exe non a path. 
And if I copy the Winsat.exe to / debug and run this code:
             Process process = new Process ();
             process.StartInfo.FileName = @ "C: \ windows \ system32 \ cmd.exe";
             process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/ c winsat formal";
             Process.Start ();
/ / It will run, but it will not work 100%, because it will modify the functioning of Winsat.exe

Comment: @SaturninoMateus and if you include the ".exe" extension ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia it will give the same initial error at: Process.Start();
:/